# Can't keep last item in navbar from dropping to next line when window resized?

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar, css-float

Trying to have a horizontal navigation bar that has equally spaced links spanning across the entire page. I have 6 links, so I figured that each one would have a 16.67% width approximately, but that doesnt work.

16.5% works, until you resize the page, at which point the last item in the nav bar drops down to the next line. Is there a way that I can prevent this so that they are centered at all times and in all window sizes?

And is there a way that I can prevent the user from resizing the window to a size that would cause the links to either overlap or not be fully displayed?

Here's my code so far:

```
#navbar {margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; width:100%;}
li      {width:100%}
li a    {padding: 6px 3px; float:left; width:16.5%; text-align:center;}

<ul id='navbar'>
<li><a href='#'> 1 </a></li>
<li><a href='#'> 2 </a></li>
<li><a href='#'> 3 </a></li>
<li><a href='#'> 4 </a></li>
<li><a href='#'> 5 </a></li>
<li><a href='#'> 6 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried a non-fractional width like just 16% ?  Also, browsers are going to handle the math differently, in which browsers is this a problem for you?

Comment: Yeah i tried 16% and it does the same thing. I'm using Safari 5. I also tried it using 5 links instead of 6 so i could do an even 20% width, but again to no avail.

Comment: See my answer below.  The left/right padding is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Safari, it's always screwed up until I remove your left/right padding.  Left/right padding is not needed since the spacing is already determined by the width and other CSS.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7Am/1/)

```
#navbar {margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; width:100%;}
li      {width:100%}
li a    {padding: 6px 0; float:left; width:16.5%; text-align:center;}
```

I'm not sure IE is going to be happy about the fractional width percentage, so try this.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7Am/5/)

```
#navbar {margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; width:100%;}
li      {width:100%}
li a    {padding: 6px 0; float:left; width:16%; text-align:center;}
```

Comment: awesome thanks... just for future reference, why would the left/right padding cause that even if you decrease 16% to 15 and leave the padding?

Comment: @Drew:  You are adding padding which increases the width by an exact number of pixels no matter what, in this case, 36 pixels over the entire menubar.  At 15% each, your menubar is supposed to be 90% wide.  When 10% of the window width is less than 36 pixels, you won't have enough room.  Please "accept" my answer by clicking the green check-mark since it solved your problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a width to the #navbar that is bigger than all the elements.